# Campaign management, Crash & Exception tracking using GTM

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to implement Google Analytics Campaign Management and Crash & Exception tracking using Google Tag Manager in Android. I found Google Analytics documentation for  Campaign Management and Crash & Exception tracking.

Links:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/exceptions

But I didn't find any documentation for implementing the same thing using Google Tag Manager.
Please suggest if there is any other way to track these things using GTM.

Answer (score 0):

**Google Analytics Campaign Management**

As far as I know, you need to map campaign parameters variables such as source and medium yourself, that's how GTM provides flexibility. On Android, we usually implement a function like :-

```
 public static void trackCampaign(String uri_string)
{
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url_string);

    DataLayer dataLayer = TagManager.getInstance(getAppContext()).getDataLayer();
    dataLayer.pushEvent("campaignTracking",
                                          DataLayer.mapOf("screenName", screenName,
                                                                        "source", uri.getQueryParameter("utm_source"),
                                                                        "medium", uri.getQueryParameter("utm_medium"));
}
```

On the GTM dashboard you can use the "Fields to set" parameters to set campaign parameters such as source and medium. Please see the image below for reference.
[image]

**Google Analytics Crash & Exception tracking **

To track crashes and exceptions one can add a Google Analytics event on a "Crash" trigger. The crash trigger can be set while handling exception. The GA event can be set in a way such that.

```
Event Category= Error
Event Action = screenName
Event Label = Stack trace
```